# Can Geofire query location if it's a child key of an autoID?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

According to GeoFire, it allows you to query *all* keys within a geographic area. If that's the case, can I query for object locations if `location` is a child key of an `autoID`?

Basically, I want to query for all messages within a geographic radius, and then sort them by recency. Is `autoID` the best key to use for identifying many objects? Let's say I have 100 messages in a defined radius, how would I identify them and subsequently retrieve them?

```
{
  "Messages" : {
    "-KFGX5H3rLSnpPvupakm" : {
      "message" : "Concert at the park!",
      "location" : {
          "g" : "xxxx",
          "l" : {
              "0": "xxx",
              "1": "xxx"
          }
      },
    },
    "-KFGZkwAIl817CLDLmMp" : {
      "message" : "It's gonna be a foggy one.",
      "location" : {
          "g" : "xxxx",
          "l" : {
              "0": "xxx",
              "1": "xxx"
          }
      },
    }
  }
}
```